# can i stop showing 'would you like to save password' while i click submit button in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[This is my code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxN5O.png)

> I have tried many different ways to skip this popup on my code.I have
>   added autocomplete="new-password/off/none/false",added dummy fields
>   before and after username and password fields.I have done password
>   (i)type="password" and (ii)type="text", In second case it worked but
>   It shows the content of password.So added css to hide but then
>   popup arises again for each clicks.I want this to be checked in safari
>   browser.

Comment: ... why would you want to hide it? It's a useful security feature and none of your business.

Comment: As per request they want it to be like that.so thats the reason i am trying on it

Comment: You could place your password field outside of the form, than on form submition could do ajax post...

Comment: can you please provide me a demo?

Comment: Maybe check some of the [examples](https://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/saS5y/), than [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/9TGJd/)... and many others... you can google it

Comment: Indeed my password should not be exposed.so even if i gave password type='text' i could skip that popup.where as password content can be viewed. so when i use css to hide the password content   then popup will be showing again as i said..  in safari browser

Comment: can any one help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: I just created this page using angular...  can any one give solution or demo?